# How does a Task work when it is on caller thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

As we know running a new `Task` is not guaranteed to make a new thread. I wonder how two chunks of code (remaining code of task caller, and task) can go together on while being on the same `thread` and meanwhile preventing the caller to block?

**Example**:

Suppose there is a windows form application with a form named `Form1` . Two events are handled:
`KeyPress` , `Click`

```
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        ...
        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
        }

        private async void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Caller threadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
           await Task.Run(() =>
           {
              var start = DateTime.Now;
              Console.WriteLine("working asynchronously on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
              while ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds < 5)
                  ;                    
           });          
       }
```

If I press a key the, for 5 seconds there are things being written in console. Meanwhile the form can handle `click` event and show message box.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did.

Comment: I suggest trying to create a very basic console program that does what you are asking, compile then decompile it. You'll see that the compiler sets up a state machine for the remaining part of the task (everything under `await`) and when the code can be run, it will resume that part of the code. This only works efficiently if its "async all-the-way" which is another reason why you want to do fully commit to async.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am aware of that. What I don't understand is who does the job of `await` part. I don't have any problem with code **after** await.

Comment: I don't know what you know, and what you don't know, but [this may be helpful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) specifically the section on "What does the await keyword do" (not insulting you, but its quite in-depth), and the section about how await relates to the syncronization context. Basically what happens is that a single thread can run multiple tasks, and it services them. `await` sets that system up and resumes on the specified synchronization context.

Comment: I don't understand this question. You ask about tasks running in the caller's thread, but then you don't show any code where that happens. There are already lots of resources out there that explain how `await` works, including the two key aspects: upon hitting `await`, **the method returns**; and when the awaited task completes, the method is re-entered in an appropriate context so that it can continue executing the code following the `await`. There's a lot of hidden plumbing that makes this all happen; if you want to know how it works, you should do some research.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Showing a message box is parallel to looping though `while`. How is this possible without threading? When a MessageBox is shown the thread blocks.

Comment: _"When a MessageBox is shown the thread blocks"_ -- first of all, no. `MessageBox` shows a dialog and in the course of doing that, pumps messages for the thread. All the normal window messaging still happens, without blocking the thread. Secondly, the `while` loop is _in a different thread_. For sure, that can run just fine, even if the UI thread were blocked (which it's not).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ok, I was mistaken by MessageBox. But how can you be sure `while` loop is on another thread? `async` method may run on current thread

Comment: @Hans, you are starting with wrong assumption. `Task.Run` body is guaranteed to be run on another thread. It doesn't need to be a "new" thread, but still "another". Or in very rare case (not in yours), even the same, but **later**. Shorty, `Task.Run` has nothing to do with `async` methods - all it does is "Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool  and returns a Task object that represents that work." - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @IvanStoev Beautiful! You are right. Can you write an `async` method without `Task.Run` ?

Comment: Yes you can - if you just use other async methods by await-ing them.  I would suggest you to read Stephen Toub blog (staring from the link provided by Ron Beyer) and also http://blog.stephencleary.com/

Comment: _"`async` method may run on current thread"_ -- yes, but a task started with `Task.Run()` can't (as Ivan says). _"Can you write an `async` method without `Task.Run()`"_ -- absolutely. I would even guess that _most_ `async` don't use `Task.Run()`. A very common asynchronous scenario is I/O, and an example of an `async` I/O method call running on the current thread would be if the I/O can be completed immediately (e.g. an OS buffer already has data ready to be returned).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you so far for you help. The last question (I hope so): Can I write a high level `async` method that **1-** is not asynchronous by nature like I/O operation **2-** doesn't call any other asynchronous-by-nature operation like I/O operations and **3-** doesn't run on current thread?

Comment: The rules are simple: to use `await` (which can release the current thread by returning from the method), you have to mark the method `async`. An `async` method that doesn't execute an `await` is legal, but will run in the current thread. By definition, if an operation is completed in the current thread, it's synchronous, not asynchronous. So for your `async` method to truly be asynchronous, it has to `await` _something_, or at least return an asynchronous "something" (i.e. `Task`).

Comment: The code in the method itself very well might run in the current thread (depending on where the code is in the method and what the current synchronization context is); but while it's waiting on something else, it's not running at all, in the current thread or otherwise.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Fantastic! If I want to `await` on a `Task`, it should already be started (am I correct?). Starting a task ends in that task be queued in the `ThreadPool`. Finally, the task might be assigned the same thread or another thread to work. Is that right?

Comment: _"it should already be started"_ -- that's up to you. That is the typical use case, but you can create a `Task` object, start `await`ing it, and then somewhere else start the task later. The code in the `async` method that `await`s the task won't be able to start the task, at least not for that particular call to the method, but there are lots of other ways to get code to execute. The task could only be assigned that current thread if the `async` method itself were executing in the thread pool (which can happen).

Comment: Note that this is specific to `Task.Run()` and similar (i.e. where the `Task` represents work done in the thread pool)...a `Task` object itself is simply a promise for something to happen, and can be implemented via any number of mechanisms (including `TaskCompletionSource`, which provides a task that can be completed without actually _doing_ anything).

Answer (score 2):

You may find my [`async`/`await` post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) useful.

As others have noted, `async` and `await` by themselves do not imply multithreading. However, `Task.Run` **does**.

So, the current code is explicitly blocking on a thread pool thread:

```
private async void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  // ** On the UI thread **
  Console.WriteLine("Caller threadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    // ** On a thread pool thread **
    Console.WriteLine("working asynchronously on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(5);
  });
  // ** On the UI thread **
}
```

Note that it is the `Task.Run` - **not** the `await` - that causes the specified code to run on a thread pool thread.

If you use pure `async`/`await` without `Task.Run`, you'll see that the code all runs on the UI thread:

```
private async void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  // ** On the UI thread **
  Console.WriteLine("Caller threadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  await DoNothingAsync();
  // ** On the UI thread **
}

private async Task DoNothingAsync()
{
  // ** On the UI thread **
  Console.WriteLine("working asynchronously on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  await Task.Delay(5); // Task.Delay is the asynchronous version of Thread.Sleep
  // ** On the UI thread **
}
```